# assigning symfony2 finder class data to array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, symfony-finder

I am working with Symfony 2.6 and the application has an `icons` directory inside `web` directly. In `icons` directory user uploads set of icons. I need to display names of those icons in a dropdown menu on a form that the `twig` will display

I know how to

1. Make Symfony forms to work
2. Send data to twig

All I need is to assign the set of icons to an array so I can pass that to twig

I am working with Symfony Finder component `use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;` and I can get the results I need using the following code in a controller

```
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->in($this->container->getParameter('icons_path'));
$finder->sortByName();
foreach ($finder as $file) {
    print pathinfo($file->getRelativePathname(), PATHINFO_FILENAME)."<br>";
}
```

The above code gives me an output that looks like this

[image]

As you can see it is not an array. I will really appreciate if I can get some assistance on how to make this an array.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes small little things makes you go crazy
This is how i did it

```
$icons[] = pathinfo($file->getRelativePathname(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

This is what complete foreach looks like

```
foreach ($finder as $file) {
    $icons[] = pathinfo($file->getRelativePathname(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}
```